# Different DocInclusionPredicate for different swagger document with Swashbuckle.AspNetCore

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I'm trying to generate multiple swagger.json documents and using [Customize the Action Selection Process](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#customize-the-action-selection-process) to determine which action goes to which swagger document.

Is it possible to have different DocInclusionPredicate for different swagger document?

For example, I have

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API - V1", Version = "v1" });
    c.SwaggerDoc("v2", new Info { Title = "My API - V2", Version = "v2" });
})
```

How do I specify one `DocInclusionPredicate` for `v1` and another `DocInclusionPredicate` for `v2` document?

Answer (score 1):

```
c.DocInclusionPredicate((docName, apiDesc) =>
{
    if (docName == "v1")
    { /* actions for v1 */ }
    else if (docName == "v2")
    { /* actions for v2 */ }
});
```

and then return `true` if the predicate belongs to the specific version or `false` if it shall be filetered out in the correct if-statement